# Javascript is not working when form is rendered through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to AJAX and Javascript on rails.

When the tab is clicked, the corresponding partial is rendered via AJAX

When the form is rendered on the page without AJAX, flatpickr works perfectly.

[flatpickr working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEC9E.png)

But when I render it with AJAX (replacing the div link with the form), the flatpickr no longer works

[flatpickr not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl7QB.png)

**task#new**

```
<div id="single_event">
  <%= link_to "Single_event", task_new_path, remote: true %>
</div>
```

**task#new.js.erb**

```
$('#single_event a').parent().html("<%= j render 'single_event_form', meeting: @meeting %>")
```

**single_event_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_with(model: meeting, local: true, :html => {:id => "flatpickr-form-single"} ) do |form| %>
    <div class="mb-6">
      <%= form.label :body %>
      <%= form.rich_text_area :body, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-6" style ="width: 30vw;">
      <%= form.label :start_time, class: 'label' %>
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between max-w-md">
        <%= form.text_field :start_time, data: { behavior: "flatpickr" }, placeholder: "Date and time select ...", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field" style ="width: 30vw;">
      <%= form.label :end_time, class: 'label' %>
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between max-w-md">
        <%= form.text_field :end_time, data: { behavior: "flatpickr" }, placeholder: "Date and time select ...", class: "form-control required" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= form.submit class: "btn btn-primary text-base py-1.5 px-5", value: "Confirm" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**flatpickt.js**

```
import flatpickr from "flatpickr"
require("flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css")

document.querySelector('#flatpickr-form-single')
    .addEventListener("ajax:success", function(data, status, xhr) {
      flatpickr("[data-behavior='flatpickr']", {
        enableTime: false,
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "F j, Y",
        minDate: "today"
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is due to initialising `flatpickr` *only on page load event*, you need to initialise it also after the AJAX request finished.

Try adding this to your `flatpickt.js` with the following and **replace with your form id** in the *querySelector* selector:

```js
...
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
  document.querySelector('#single_event a')
    .addEventListener("ajax:success", function(data, status, xhr) {
      flatpickr("[data-behavior='flatpickr']", {
        enableTime: false,
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "F j, Y",
        minDate: "today"
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @plamen. I added a ID to my form of `#flatpickr-form-single`, then followed your step and added that as my query selector: `document.querySelector('#flatpickr-form-single')`.  This came back with a console error of `flatpickr.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: @Lorenzo_xavier such error means that `document.querySelector` returns null - this can be due to misspelling the the form identifier or the script is executed before the form to be in the DOM.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm in one of those 10 tabs open and no solutions to fix the underlying issue! There is definitely no spelling mistakes on the id. How do you execute the script after the form is rendered by the ajax?

Comment: @Lorenzo_xavier can you update the question with the latest code, including the form ID? (both in HTML and JS)?

Comment: I have updated the code in the question to reflect the additional steps you suggested

Comment: the full error that comes up with this change is:

Comment: ```flatpickr.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/flatpickr.js (flatpickr.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83```

Comment: @Lorenzo_xavier I see that you have added the id to a `<div>` tag not to the `<form>` tag... you need to either change the selector to  `querySelector('#select-your-form-by-id form')` or to move the `id="flatpickr-form-single"` attribute to the `<form>` tag.

Comment: sorry, that was really stupid of me. I have added the corrected code to the form and I inspected the form to check the id was attached to it: ```<form id="flatpickr-form-single" action="/meetings" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="NmfdmeRULLRjhWmwH0ryD55jxlRT2F0Dx9cvck+Wemjbn+X+X7M9ABbNs+aCCyUagITxf9q23JthRadMGH02+A==">``` . It is still coming up with the same error: ```flatpickr.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null```

Comment: @Lorenzo_xavier I've updated my answer - I've added the `Turbolinks:load' event listener - do you use Turbolinks - https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks?

Comment: Thank you so much, that edited code worked perfectly. I changed the query selector to ```'#single_event a``` in your edited code and it loaded the javascript after ajax replaced the parent of single_event to the form. I am going to be doing a lot of study on this now. I was pulling my hair out trying to find a solution!

Comment: @Lorenzo_xavier can you mark/accept my answer as correct in this case?